# How can I GET the parameters from URL in django

Tags: python, django, url, get

I'm trying to send a parameter by URL and trying to use it in a listview. But I cant GET it in my view. I know I'm doing some stupid mistake, but can't find it.

This is the link I'm using in my template:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'listarmateriales' tipolista='metales' %}">Ver metales
```

This is my url.py:

```
path('listarmateriales/<tipolista>',listarmateriales.as_view(), name='listarmateriales'),
```

And this is where I try to get the "tipolista" in my views.py:

class listarmateriales(ListView):

```
 template_name = 'materiales/materialeslist.html'
 
   def get_queryset(self):
     if self.request.GET.get('tipolista') is not None:
        lista=Materiales.objects.all()
        tipolista=self.request.GET.get('tipolista' '')
        if tipolista=='metales':
            Do whatever...
        
        else:
```

I have tried some different sintaxis, but the result is always the same, I cant read "tipolista", I have spent a lot of time with this, too much. I know it must be something easy, but, I'm new at this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are *not* GET parameters, these are the URL parameters. These are stored in `self.kwargs`, so you access these with:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    lista = Materiales.objects.all()
    tipolista = self.kwargs['tipolista']
    if tipolista=='metales':
        # …
    else:
        # …
```

these can not be `None`, since these exist in order to "fire" the view.

Answer (score 1):

For the urls.py to recognize tipolista as a string variable, you should pass tipolista as a view paramater. So, your view function should be something like this:

```
def get_queryset(self, tipolista):
 if self.request.GET.get('tipolista') is not None:
    lista=Materiales.objects.all()
    
    if tipolista=='metales':
        #...
    
    else:
        #...
```

And in your url pattern, tipolista must be preceded by 'str':

```
path('listarmateriales/<str:tipolista>',listarmateriales.as_view(), name='listarmateriales'),
```

Comment: I have tried your sugestion, and I get this error message: "get_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tipolista'" How can I solve it?

Comment: In your template, instead of `tipolista='metales'` try using just `'metales'`. Like this `<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'listarmateriales' 'metales' %}">Ver metales`